# What is the plastic blister chemical compound that stores plastic toys?

Tags: chemical-engineering

I have observed that plastic toys that are stored in the plastic blisters, which is transparent, tends to stay the same over a long time. There are no chemical reaction taking place even after decades of storage.

I am specifically asking about the plastic toys like Hot Wheels and Matchbox. I would like to know what is the chemical compound used for such stable use.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer a question like this I would look up blister packaging and see what materials are commonly used:

[Blister packaging article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_pack#Materials)

Note the article I have linked above suggests some possibilities: PVC (polyvinyl chloride), PVDC (Polyvinylidene_chloride) and PCTFE (Polychlorotrifluoroethylene).

My guess is the most likely material is PVC by the way (it seems to be very common in packs I have looked at).

I would also look for a [recycling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resin_identification_code) embossed on the material, for example PVC is a triangle with a "3" inside it. (The code is not always put on packs though.)

Comment: There were no recycle codes, and that is why I decided to ask this question and I am curious as to understand which materials do not start any chemical reactions with plastic toys.

Comment: Why not ask the manufacturer of the toys what the material is?